# Displaying titles inline with logo

Tags: html, css

Trying to have a center Title with a slogan below then on the right side I want to display my Logo.

Here is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/xhRnG/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
George

```
<div id="titles">
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>This is the slogan</h2>
<p><img id="logo" src="http://www.pressuredesigns.com/themes/pala/files/stacks_image_154.png"/></p></div>
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/xhRnG/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a tiny modification....something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xhRnG/7/?

HTML:

```
<div id="titles">
    <div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>This is the slogan</h2>
    </div>
            <p><img id="logo" src="http://www.pressuredesigns.com/themes/pala/files/stacks_image_154.png"/></p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#titles
{
 text-align: center;   
}

#titles div, #titles p
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I wrapped the h1 and h2 inside a div in order to have them at the same time in a block level along the p

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="titles" style="text-align:center">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>This is the slogan</h2>
        <p style="float:right; position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px"><img id="logo" src="http://www.pressuredesigns.com/themes/pala/files/stacks_image_154.png"/></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a centered table that's 100% wide, with three cells: the one in the middle contains your title, the one on the right the logo, and the one on the left is empty. You need that one on the left so you can center the title on the page.

```
<div id="titles">
    <table width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"></td>
            <td width="60%" align="center">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2>This is the slogan</h2></td>
            <td width="20%">
                <img id="logo" src="http://www.pressuredesigns.com/themes/pala/files/stacks_image_154.png"/></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: tables should be used to display tabular data. To position elements on a page css is enougth

Comment: I won't argue with you, and concede you have a point - the only thing I can say in defense of the above is that tables work with really old browsers...

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do that: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xhRnG/4/)**

**CSS**

```
h1, h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="titles">
    <p><img id="logo" src="http://www.pressuredesigns.com/themes/pala/files/stacks_image_154.png" /></p>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>This is the slogan</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `SOMEWIDTH` with a good value, and `LOGOWITH` with width of your logo. Then replace `TOTAL_WIDTH` with sum of both;

```
<div id="titles" style="width: TOTAL_WIDTH; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:SOMEWITH; float:left;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Title</h1>
        <h2 style="text-align: right;">This is the slogan</h2>
    </div>
    <p style="width: LOGOWIDTH; float: right;">
        <img id="logo" src="http://www.pressuredesigns.com/themes/pala/files/stacks_image_154.png"/>
    </p>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I've just changed the first p to div, it was a mistake :P
Also an example for numbers: TOTAL_WIDTH=270px, SOMEWIDTH=140px, LOGOWIDTH=130px.